# How to not use localhost, but the IP of the server instead?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I found this node application on [this tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/03/nodejs-private-webchat/) and wanted to use it, but it's configured to run as localhost. Since the application is run on Amazon Linux EC2, there is no desktop (local) access to it (maybe there's software to install to enable desktop mode, but I haven't got that).

I'd like to run the application on the server, not on localhost, but on the server's Elastic IP address which I'll be adding to a Hosted Zone of my domain chatxs.com.

I'd like to make the app listen for any requests in this IP, which again, will be in the domain name's DNS.

Here's the code the tutorial comes with, the only thing I've changed is the .html files in the views folder (styling, alignment and some text, no code changes of the app, just the html):

**app.js**

```
// This is the main file of our chat app. It initializes a new 
// express.js instance, requires the config and routes files
// and listens on a port. Start the application by running
// 'node app.js' in your terminal

var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

// This is needed if the app is run on heroku:

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Initialize a new socket.io object. It is bound to 
// the express app, which allows them to coexist.

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
// Require the configuration and the routes files, and pass
// the app and io as arguments to the returned functions.

require('./config')(app, io);
require('./routes')(app, io);

console.log('Your application is running on http://localhost:' + port);
```

**config.js**

```
// This file handles the configuration of the app.
// It is required by app.js

var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app, io){

// Set .html as the default template extension
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// Initialize the ejs template engine
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// Tell express where it can find the templates
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// Make the files in the public folder available to the world
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

};
```

[routes.js](http://pastebin.com/r1jbk0M8) it was too big to format it here.

And finally

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "NodeChatSystem",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Realtime chat system for Tutorialzine.com",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [
  "node",
  "chat",
  "system"
],
"author": "Nikolay Anastasov",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
  "ejs": "^1.0.0",
  "express": "^4.8.2",
  "gravatar": "~1.0.6",
  "socket.io": "^1.0.6"
  }
}
```

The above is basically what's included in the tutorial .zip file.

Comment: Just deploy your application on your server at `52.19.7.59` (i.e. put all the code on that server and run the application). When you hit that IP address + the port you specify, you'll be hitting that application.

Comment: It should just work if you are running this on AWS.  If you haven't done so make sure you are allowing access for incoming traffic on the port in question in the AWS console.

Comment: @Houseman thanks for the quick feedback. I'm embarrased to ask this, but how to deploy it, I am confused with this stuff but I really want it up and running. I only understand html css so far :(

Comment: @Darth_nVade_Her if you are looking to deploy and run node.js on a EC2 server, this link http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2014/12/setup-nodejs-enviroment-on-amazon-ec2-linux-1.html should help you.

Along with the answer from MattHouser  you should be able to run the nodejs app

Comment: @Raghav I actually used this tutorial to setup the server, all I did afterwards is just to edit tutorial html and upload it. Then I ran "npm install" and once it was done "node app.js"

Comment: @Darth_nVade_Her Did you modify in app.js the line

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

to 

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0"));

and then run the node

Comment: @Raghav yup that's the only line I've changed (+ the html) and ran it, produces error like the one in my comment to Matt

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/355382/node-js-amazon-ec2-example-webserver-no-result

Comment: Here's a great overall tutorial on setting up a node.js web server on EC2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxhFq64FQzA

Comment: @jfriend00 ok im getting somewhere, i changed the ip used to the Private Server IP and I've loaded up it up on port 8080 but whenever I change it to 80 it still gives errors. It's possible to access it here http://52.19.7.59:8080/ but no styles or functionality works

Comment: On port 80, is the error EACCESS?  If so, that's because you aren't running your server as root.  The video above offers options on what to do about that.

Comment: Since you aren't showing your routes code, there's not much we can do to help with why stylesheets and other resources aren't loading.  I presume that either the files aren't in the right sub-directory on your server or the routes are not declared correctly.  I would suggest not using "../somefile" as paths.  Just use "/somefile" or "/somepath/somefile" and manage your routes accordingly.  You really don't want stylesheet paths to depend upon the path of the page they're in.  You want them to be absolute on your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 :O damnit i knew there was something to do with sudo in the back of my head. sudo solves most of the stuff, thanks for that tip! now, I have to figure out how to get the styles and functionality going :/

Comment: @jfriend00 alright i'll look around and link it up, thanks for all of the help :)

Comment: OK, I didn't realize the `express.static()` lines are already in your question on config.js.  If those aren't working, then something doesn't match between the actual location of the static files in your file system (relative to your app directory) and the paths you're using in your HTML.  I suspect this is an issue where you're telling  `express.static()` to look in the `__dirname/public` directory, but then you're request `/public/somefile` which means express.static is looking for `__dirname/public/public/somefile`.

Comment: But, the `express.static()` stuff regularly confuses me and sometimes I only get unconfused by actually stepping through a given request to see what it is actually looking for to understand what it thinks I've told it to do.  In any case, you probably have a path mismatch between the path in your HTML, how you've configured `express.static()` and where you put the files in your server.

Answer (score 5):

When you simply use `app.listen(port)`, it will only allow connections from localhost (as you are seeing).

To permit external connections, use `app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0")`. This tells Node to listen on the external network interfaces.

Also, make sure your EC2 instance's security group is allowing incoming connections on the appropriate port.

**Update:**

As pointed out by jfriend00, and further investigation, this is not correct.

Ref: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen

Comment: I did it and when I ran it, this came up http://imgur.com/GzkcxTh . Am I supposed to have the outer brackets too? Like (app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0")) or as you've put it?

Comment: Your server is running on the port. The error looks like some kind of runtime error (not a compile or syntax error).

Comment: Try trapping the error and printing it to see what it is.

Comment: This is simply not correct.  `app.listen(port)` does not limit connections to only be from localhost.  I have a server running with `app.listen(port)` and it accepts connections from any host on my network.

Comment: @Darth_nVade_Her can you verify if there is already something running on port 8080?

Comment: Though this answer might not be completely correct, at least it demonstrates the actual code to listen on a different IP... It's kinda trivial to fill in another IP so I don't get the very low rating... Probably the elastic IP will be available in some environment variable... I don't know much about AWS but on Heroku that env var is called HOST if i remember correctly. So code would be `app.listen(port, process.env.HOST)`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I think that you are confused about networking and IP addresses. The `localhost` is reserved hostname for IP address 127.0.0.1 and is equivalent to say `THIS COMPUTER`. You can read more about localhost on [official wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Secondly, I would highly encourage you to delete your EC2 instance and don't use it for now. If you are beginner, there is plenty of options which are for free and are more user friendly. For example Heroku is great platform to start on. I highly recommend you to start with their tutorial - [Getting Started with Nodejs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs). Try first develop simple app there and deploy to Heroku. Some **unintentional mistakes**(expose configuration and passwords on Github, opening Ports, exposing public IP addresses, etc.) **on EC2 can costs you thousands of dollars in period of few minutes**. So I would recommend to get back to EC2 later, once you are more experienced. ***Heroku is also free for one app***, so it won't cost you anything and it is really simple to setup. You can also setup your own domain.

When you say:

> What I'd like to do is basically run the application on the server,
>   not on localhost, but on the server's Elastic IP address which I'll be
>   adding to a Hosted Zone of my domain chatxs.com.

I assume that you are trying to release your application to your own server. I'm not going to write step by step how to deploy Node app to a server, I think you should use some other hosting. But if you would like to know more about running Node app in production environemnt, I think that [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial can give you glimpse of what is all needed.

Finally, it should be mentioned, that **you should never, ever expose sensitive information on the internet.** Delete the public ip address from your question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the detailed answer, I got too excited about this and went straight into the pro stuff. Baby steps for now :D I'll checkout the tutorial and see what I can do. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Darth_nVade_Her, don't worry, we all have been there. Good luck with that!

Comment: Uhhh, since when is a public IP address sensitive information?  It's public.

Comment: @jfriend00 a public ip address is sensitive when it gives people a reason to look for it, like in this post.

Comment: @Darth_nVade_Her: use vpc in private subnets with an elb in the frontend.

Comment: Since an IP address that's hooked to a hostname via DNS can be obtained from any URL/hostname by just looking it up in DNS, you're essentially saying that nobody should publicly post URLs or hostnames?  I don't get it.  A public website is public.  Most sites want MORE viewers not less viewers.  Public facing IP addresses are not a secret.

Comment: I have same opinion as @ptierno. Don't know if it's a crime or what exactly do you try to achieve with your aggressive post, but I believe that it's always better expose as less information as you could. It's my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me..
just allow tcp connection to the port,
use the below command `sudo ufw allow 5000/tcp`
here i used port 5000,
change it according to your port number.
Reference : https://blog.cloudboost.io/deploying-a-node-js-express-application-on-digital-ocean-part-1-5d5b0cfe0a34

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about the firewall.