# Connection Refused on Amazon Web Services

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, networking

Can't access node.js API on port 3000 on AWS EC2 instance, but `netstat` shows port :3000 listening and my AWS security group has TCP rules for this port. What else could the problem be?

I've tried changing port, setting security group rules and adding port to `iptables` and it didn't work. I'm using node 10.6.0.

When I use `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` it contains the following line:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8270/node
```

[image: netstat print]

[image: Security Group Inbound Rules]

When i try to access `myip:3000/socket` (my node endpoint) it shows: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Looks like node is listening on loopback only, like shown in the netstat output. It should look like `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:3000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8270/node` or `tcp 0 0 :::3000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 8270/node`, so use `server.listen(3000)` instead

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043926/node-js-connect-only-works-on-localhost and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837563/how-to-not-use-localhost-but-the-ip-of-the-server-instead

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks guys, completely forgot to change from 127.0.0.1(on my dev enviroment) to 0.0.0.0 on deploying

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer^